# Can custom roms like aim rom or aex increase gaming performance over stock Android?

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, stock-android, motorola-moto-g, overclocking

Note: I have zero technical knowledge about Android or custom roms or root etc. 
Am using Moto G5 plus (4bg) and I play games like PES 2019 and pubgm a lot.
Now my device runs these games with some lags but playable,but in order to get competitive edge I need to get more fps,that's why am considering ways to improve performance,even at the cost of short term heating and more power consumption.Any advice?

Comment: I would estimate that 99% of the performance (CPU, GPU...) is determined by the hardware, not the software (furthermore on Android GPU drivers are usually not updated to get more performance on popular games like it is done for PCs). If the hardware throttles e.g. because of temperature it does it for good reason. Therefore installing a different ROM will most likely not change your gaming experience. Try to play with connected charger - some devices detect that and don't try to save power while connected.

Comment: Maybe your correct,but in my friend's Oneplus2,the game lagged quite badly, almost unplayable,but when I went to the developer options and turned on gaming mode,the performance was considerably better, of course there was heating and more  battery consumption.So I was wondering if roms or software could do something.